# details of index.array function in R

Tags: r

I am going through the boot function in the boot library in R so I can replicate it myself - doing so as I am getting an error message when running boot with the model I estimated.

While doing so I came across the index.array command

`i <- index.array(n, R, sim, strata, m, L, weights)`

I could not find any math in Google for "index.array"  related to R - I feel I am missing something obvious but the only option I had was to ask here.

How does index.array work and what does it do?

Thanks!

Comment: The `index.array` function is an un-exported function from the `boot` package. You can view it's source by running `boot:::index.array`. It's a private function so it's not documented because you aren't meant to use it directly.

Comment: thanks I did not realise I would need to specify "boot:::" to see the function - I had tried "boot::" but had no luck - thanks for this